# Token Generation

Tags: curl, authorization, token

How to get user Authentication by using Tokens by adding username and password as headers. For example, the below mentioned command line would do the task but how to implement it  from the browser, without using CURL. That is I should give my username:password in the URL and the response should be a JSON file containing the Token.
The CURL command be like:->

```
curl https://api.drivr.com/authorizations \
-u john:doe -d '' \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.drivr.v2+json' \
-H 'Content-type: application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this from browser then you can pass the authorization header within url as below format

```
https://user:pass@api.drivr.com/authorizations
        ---------
```

But it is not possible to pass other headers like `Accept`, `Content-Type`, etc from your browser unless you modify your browser property (so far I know)!